# How do I set the right margin of a UITextView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextview

I have a vertically-scrolling UITextView that fills the width of the screen. I need the text view to have margins (contentInset) of 20 pixels on the left and the right. But for some reason, I can't get the right-hand margin to work, either in Interface Builder or in XCode.

The reason I can't just make the text view narrower is because I am adding a subview which needs to run the full width of the screen. Also, I can't turn subview clipping off, because it plays havoc with a load of other elements on the screen.

Anyone know why the contentInset property is not affecting the right margin?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could add an intermediate view that can be the superview to your text view and what was previously it's subview.

> ```
> New View with Frame(0,0,width,height)
>  ->TextView with Frame(20,0,width-20,height)     
>  ->Subview with Frame(0,0,width,height)
> ```

Comment: This won't make the subview scroll with the text view, which may be what is desired.

I would've expected UIScrollView.contentInset to work, though.